# Pandas str.fullmatch unusual behaviour with NaN

Tags: python, pandas, match

When a column of a pandas Dataframe contains only NaN, str.fullmatch throws:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

The following 2 behave as expected:

```
data1 = [ ['2022-03-15 00:00:00'], [np.NaN] ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['Date'] )
df = df.loc[ df.Date.str.fullmatch( '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s00:00:00', na=True ) ]
print(df)

data1 = [ [np.NaN], ['2022-03-15 00:00:00'] ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['Date'] )
df = df.loc[ df.Date.str.fullmatch( '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s00:00:00', na=True ) ]
print(df)
```

Only when the column is entirely NaN is the error thrown:

```
data1 = [ [np.NaN], [np.NaN] ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['Date'] )
dateRegex = '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s00:00:00'
df = df.loc[ df.Date.str.fullmatch(dateRegex, na=True) ]
```

Should it not fill the NaN as True and thus be accepted with loc as it does for the other two above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a Series with only NaN values, the dtype of the Series is `float` since `NaN` is a `float`:

```
>>> s = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan])
>>> s.dtype
dtype('float64')

>>> s.str
...
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

You need to convert it to the `object` (not necessarily `str` ;) dtype before you can use `.str`:

```
>>> s.astype(object).str
<pandas.core.strings.accessor.StringMethods at 0x122deb1c0>
```

So...

```
data1 = [ [np.NaN], [np.NaN] ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['Date'])
dateRegex = '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s00:00:00'
df.Date = df.Date.astype(object)  # <--- Add this line
df = df.loc[ df.Date.str.fullmatch(dateRegex, na=True) ]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Date
0  NaN
1  NaN
```